# Bounding all analytic functions satisfying condition

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following problem:

Let $D = \{z ∈ C : |z| \lt 1\}$ and let $f : D → C$ be analytic

Show that there is a constant $C$ independent of $f$ such that if $f(0) = 1$ and
$f(z) \notin  (-\infty, 0]$ for all $z \in D$ then $|f(z)|\leq C$ whenever $|z| \leq 1/2$.

I've been given a hint to consider the principle branch of $z^{1/2}$ but can't see a useful way to use it

Comment: I think you mean $(-\infty, 0]$.

Answer (score 1):

The branch cut of the principal branch of $z^{1/2}$ is $(-\infty, 0]$.  If $f$ satisfies the hypotheses, $f(z)^{1/2}$ is analytic, mapping $D$ to the right half plane.  Take a suitable
fractional linear transformation and you get $g \circ f$ analytic from $D$ to $D$.  Then apply the Schwarz lemma.

Comment: does $\frac{z-1}{z+1}$ work?